# C++ Rewriting a recursive function to nonrecursive - involves MPIR & very difficult

Tags: c++, gmp

I am having a really hard time coverting a function from recursive to a nonrecursive
function that uses MPIR's library variable, "mpz_t" instead of "unsigned __int64". I am also trying to think about how I should be writing the loops. When I made it recursive, it was easy but when I try to make it nonrecursive, its hard!

```
unsigned __int64 exampleFunc( unsigned __int64 a,
                              unsigned __int64 b,
                              unsigned __int64 c )
{
    if( a <= 2 )
        return a + 1;
    if( b <= 4 )
        return b;
    if( c == 3 )
        return c - 1;
    if( b == 5 )
        c += 2;
    // How will I put these into a loop?
    return exampleFunc( a - 1, b - 2, c ) + exampleFunc( 0, b + 1, c - 1 );
};
```

Part of the problem is that we can not write a function that returns an mpz_t value.
We could only write a value to it (like a pointer). So, something like this
will not work:

```
mpz_t exampleFunc( ... );
```

Which means, something like this could work:

```
void exampleFunc( mpz_t out, ... );
```

Or even a global variable (not highly recommended):

```
mpz_t g_out;
mpz_init( g_out );
void exampleFunc( ... ) { g_out = ? };
```

**Note:**

We should try not to use array or even a vector because the numbers will be very very big - which explains why I am switching from unsigned __int64 to mpz_t. UNLESS we really have to...

Please help, I am really stressing out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the question about gmp: try to use gmpxx.h  - you can return the `mpz_class` object just like you would return an integer.

```
mpz_class withgmp( const mpz_class &a, const mpz_class &b, mpz_class c )
{
    if( a <= 2 )
        return a + 1;
    if( b <= 4 )
        return b;
    if( c == 3 )
        return c - 1;
    if( b == 5 )
        c += 2;
    return withgmp( a - 1, b - 2, c ) + withgmp( 0, b + 1, c - 1 );
}
```

note that i passed `c` by value, since it is possibly modified in the function.

alternatively, if you must use plain C, you should pass a fourth parameter for the result, like this:

```
void withmpz( mpz_t a, mpz_t b, mpz_t c, mpz_t result)
{
     // ... leaving out the boundary conditions
     mpz_t left; mpz_init(left);
     // ... leaving out code for adjusting a,b and c
     withmpz(a,b,c, left);
     mpz_t rightt; mpz_init(right);
     // ... leaving out code for adjusting a,b and c
     withmpz(a,b,c, right);
     mpz_add(result, left, right);
}
```

Beware that mpz_t looks as if it is passed by value, but in reality it is always passed by reference, so a,b,c  will have changed after calling `withmpz`

The second part of your question, how to convert this to an iteration, is indeed more difficult. One way would be to change it into a stack based algorithm, where each iteration step replaces the top of the stack with the 2 values that need to be added, until one can be calculated immediately, then add it to the final result, repeat this until no more values are on your stack.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a pointer might be the solution: you pass by value the pointer to the pointer and modify the pointer and the data it points to as you wish